# Ubuntu 10.10 desktop edition installation fails

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtual-machine, md5

I just tried to set up a VM using VirtualBox and Ubuntu 10.10 desktop edition. Installation proceeded fine, but at ~60-80% I got a message that it failed and it's most likely a defect CD or a read error. So I checked the MD5 sum of the ISO (ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso) which gave me `5f4ab3c8e40f8dda084213caa842325c`, but should be `59d15a16ce90c8ee97fa7c211b7673a8` according to various sources, including the [official MD5 site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/MD5SUMS).

I redownloaded and got the same wrong MD5 sum, after that I used the BitTorrent download - still the same wrong sum. All downloads were made from http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download ,  I'm trying a third download right now from [german CHIP](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Ubuntu-10.10-Maverick-Meerkat_22592231.html), perhaps this will give the correct MD5 sum (EDIT: No, this even gives another wrong one: `0eb8d63d6eba4710754a36e123b4c4c3`).

I tried different MD5 sum checkers (no difference) and googled for the MD5 sum (0 hits). My PC is a netbook with Windows 7 Starter.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Got the correct MD5 sum now by downloading via BitTorrent again. Memory and HD seem to be OK, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to grab the torrent was a good move. Most BitTorrent clients will let you re-check downloads, which will quickly tell you if your download is corrupted.

Now for the bad news: the fact that you downloaded the ISO file from multiple sources and still ended up with corrupted files points to a possible hardware problem on your netbook (most likely a damaged hard drive controller). To see if this is the case, use another PC to download the same ISO file. Run a hash check on that PC to verify a clean download. Then, copy the ISO over to your netbook and run a hash check again.

Another way of looking for controller problems is to open uTorrent (or your BitTorrent client of choice) and force re-check everything you've downloaded in the last few weeks. If a bunch of your downloads change from `100% done` to `99% done` (or any similar number), your hard drive controller is at fault.

Comment: Accepting this answer, this would've been my next moves (additional, I'll do the memtest Nighthawk suggested). I'll update the question with further results in the next days.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to run memtest86 to verify that your memory isn't bad.  It's possible that you've got a few bad spots in RAM that are corrupting your downloads.  If you can get a known good copy of an Ubuntu CD, you can boot the netbook off of it and start memtest86 from there.  You can also get a standalone version [here](http://www.memtest86.com/)

Comment: Good idea. No CD drive on the netbook, I'll try with an USB stick.